# Issue with Canonical URL in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, seo

I just have issue with google analytics. I've a website which is developed using php. Now i wanted to make my website into non-canonical format. I followed the below coding. but still google analytics fails to recognise canonical URL.

**Coding**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; echo $url;?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Tracking ID']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
echo $url;
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

when i tried to print the $url it prints url in canonical format. but its not recognised by google analytics. can anyone tell me whats the problem with this coding??

Comment: Can you show the HTML that `<link rel="canonical" href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; echo $url;?>">` produces? Maybe substitute the TLD with example.com

Comment: I'm passing the id to this file. if i give the url as http://example.com/canonical.php?id=10 it gives canonical form as http://example.com/canonical.php..

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite realize what you are doing until now, but it looks like Elke Pierstorff knows what's up

Comment: I want to convert my URL which is of example.com/file.php?id=10 to canonical format example.com/file.php.. thats it. if u know how to do let me know bro..

Comment: I get it, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually passing you canonical url to Google Analytics - for that you need a "virtual url", by passing the value you want as second parameter to the pageview call:

```
[...]
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', <?php echo $url ?> ]);
[...]
```

Comment: Thought this would give solution for my issue. Still google analytics recognise non-canonical format only..

Comment: Yup, Ur coding is working now..

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<?php echo; $url ?>' ]);

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

> Google currently supports these link header elements for Web Search
>   only.

So it sounds like your analytics are still going to tell you the full link whereas Googling your site will show what you desire.

If this is a recent change then I would recommend checking Google search results in 1-2 weeks.

If you are running Apache then **mod_rewrite** might be what you are looking for:

http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Specifically the `mod-rewrite Regular Expressions` section